# Padé approximants with $m+n$ fixed

Tags: real-analysis, rational-functions, pade-approximation

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant#Definition) it says that the $[m/n]_f$ Padé approximant to a function $f(x)$ is the rational function
$$R(x)=\frac{a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_m x^m}{1+b_1 x+\cdots+b_n x^n} $$
such that $$R^{(k)}(0)=f^{(k)}(0) $$
for all $0 \leq k \leq m+n$.

This definition makes me think that $[m+n/0]_f,[m+n-1/1]_f,\dots,[0/m+n]_f$ are all a "similar class" in terms of the amount of accuracy provided. My questions are: What sets them apart? Is there anything more significant than the number of zeros/poles? Which one is the best choice when trying to approximate a given function to degree $m+n$?

Thank you!

Comment: They are set apart by the fact that they are different functions, there is nothing more to it. As for the best choice, it can be any of them - that depends on the function you approximate.